# Is it safe to clear cache of Symfony project

Tags: symfony, caching

I have a Symfony 5 project in production and I need to update some css and twig files for the moment.
What cache should I clear Updates to take effect?

```
php bin/console cache:pool:list
Pool name                                         
 -------------------------------------------------- 
  cache.app                                         
  cache.system                                      
  cache.validator                                   
  cache.serializer                                  
  cache.annotations                                 
  cache.property_info                               
  doctrine.result_cache_pool                        
  doctrine.system_cache_pool                        
  cache.property_access                             
  cache.security_expression_language                
  api_platform.cache.route_name_resolver            
  api_platform.cache.identifiers_extractor          
  api_platform.cache.subresource_operation_factory  
  api_platform.cache.metadata.resource              
  api_platform.cache.metadata.property
```

Do I need perform any other actions? Sorry I'm new to Symfony but I need solve the task. Hope you could help.

Comment: I could be wrong but, I think it is always safe to clear any/all of the cache. It will just slow down only the very first request (by anyone) to each path so you could visit each path yourself afterwards. But I have also not worked with the whole new cache pools.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly safe to clear the cache in a Symfony project (`bin/console cache:clear`), the command also re-builds the cache (also known as warm up) at the same time & you shouldn't see a significant slow down compared to if you nuked the cache by removing the `var/cache/*` folders directly.

You mentioned you were trying to edit CSS files. These are not cached by Symfony but by the browser so make sure that you've also cleared your browser cache.

Depending on your production stack, there is probably a CDN or a server responsible for caching the assets ([Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/), etc.) so make sure you clear these caches as well if you don't see any changes.

I assume you're using [Symfony Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html), as you mentioned that you were also trying to edit SCSS files, in that case, in order to re-compile the assets after they've been edited, you must execute the following command: `yarn build` or `encore production --progress`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the entire `dev` or `prod` cache directory in complete safety. The only effect you will see is a short delay on the next page load/cli access as the files are rebuilt. removing any single file is also ok.

Comment: I tried to edit scss or twig files, then 
php bin/console cache:clear
[OK] Cache for the "prod" environment (debug=false) was successfully cleared.
but no updates on the site.